# Suitable database for correlated events

Tags: database, workflow

I'm thinking about storing history of a workflow engine. There are hundreds of different *pipelines* defined.

The goal is to track "life cycle" of inbound data. Thus execution of each pipeline step should be logged along with pipeline&step specific metadata.

---

Example of simple pipelines:

- Pipeline A = **read JSON from FS** | **validate** | **split JSON array** | **send parts via JMS**
- Pipeline B = **ingest XML via JMS** | **validate** | **store to a batch** | **check stored batch size** | **if reached batch size merge XMLs** | **send via HTTP**

---

We currently got *~200k* different stage executions/events per day. It would be sufficient to set event TTL to a month or so.

---

So far the model correlates all steps of a pipeline execution by inbound data UUID. Results of splits, batches, merges, etc. are assigned different UUIDs and the parent relation is stored.

- **Pipeline A**

[image]

- **Pipeline B**

[image]

---

We need to perform *listing queries* like: "give me last N events" or "give me last N unique UUIDs sorted by newest events". Also queries like: "give me all related UUIDs to UUID A".

A brief experimenting with graph DBs or RDF DBs shows that they are rather slow with the listing queries - ordering the whole data set, etc.

So we will probably use classic Postgres due it's speed. Any alternatives?